# How to properly write a UDP packet

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, packet, bytebuffer

I am trying to rewrite some of my code from a C++ program I wrote a while ago, but I am not sure if/how I can write to a byte array properly, or if I should be using something else. The code I am trying to change to C# .NET is below.

```
unsigned char pData[1400];
bf_write g_ReplyInfo("SVC_ReplyInfo", &pData, 1400);

void PlayerManager::BuildReplyInfo()
{   
    // Delete the old packet
    g_ReplyInfo.Reset();

    g_ReplyInfo.WriteLong(-1);
    g_ReplyInfo.WriteByte(73);
    g_ReplyInfo.WriteByte(g_ProtocolVersion.GetInt());
    g_ReplyInfo.WriteString(iserver->GetName());
    g_ReplyInfo.WriteString(iserver->GetMapName());
}
```

Comment: After more searching, I found BinaryWriter and MemoryStream, and everything seems to be working. Only issue I am having now is I can't specify when overload to use for Write(), so am I going to have to manually convert the longs and shorts to bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BinaryWriter` might work, although strings are written with a preceding 7-bit encoded length, which I suspect the client won't be able to handle.  You'll probably have to convert strings to bytes and then either add a length word or 0-terminate it.

No need to manually convert numbers to bytes.  If you have a `long` that you want to write as a `byte`, just cast it. That is, if your `BinaryWriter` is `bw`, then you can write `bw.Write((byte)longval);`. To write `-1` as a long: `bw.Write((long)(-1))`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense, guess I was over thinking it. When I was using it with just bw.Write(-1), and bw.Write("strings like this"); it atleast responded to the query, the information just wasn't formatted right so it wasn't showing properly. Now that I have cast the values to byte/long/short, and cast the strings to byte arrays and null terminated them, it no longer works at all. Probably best to make a new post for this though, hard to paste code in comments, thank you!